# How does the router know to which device it should forward the packet

Tags: networking, ip, router, packet

I was studying about packets and networking and i think that the packet have a header which contain source address and destination ...

but since the destination is the IP of the router so after the packet reach the router how does the router know which device it should forward the packet like 192.168.1.2? or 192.168.1.3?

or does the packet contain the internal IP too

thanks for any answers .

Comment: "_but since the destination is the IP of the router_" That is simply incorrect. The destination address is the destination host. Routers route packets based on the destination address. A router has a routing table, and it looks for the closest match of the destination address. If there is not match, then it drops the packet. You could have a default route `0.0.0.0/0` in the routing table that matches every address, so any packets not matching any other entry in the routing table, it will follow the default route.

Comment: Thanks ,  so the destination host is something like publicIP/privateIP (212.152.24.36/192.168.1.7)

Comment: You seem to be confusing routing with NAT. You use NAT only when necessary (public<->private or overlapping addressing), but routing is something completely different. NAT replaces either or both the source and destination addresses in a packet header. That has nothing to do with routing. Routers or firewalls are a convenient place to perform the NAT.

Comment: For learning about networking there´s nothing like [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org) plus the protocol descriptions (for example start with [IP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Protocol) then move up (i. e. TCP) or down (i. e. Ethernet)...